# How do I add a ScrollView to a constraint layout?

Tags: android, xml

I'm very new at coding, I'm in Android Basics at Udacity. I have a constraint layout with various TextViews and ImageViews and need to add a scroll bar for an assignment.
I tried adding the scrollview outside of the layout, that made the app crash, then in the layout with the other views as children of the scrollview within the constraint layout, but an error came up stating that there can be only one child for the scroll view. Why is that? How do I add a scrollview?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#990099" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Words"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#990099"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Words"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#990099"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Words"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#990099"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
`
```

UPDATE I tried this, but the app crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `ScrollView`, it can only have one child. You'll usually want to use a `LinearLayout`, and that is where you'll put your actual content.

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
         <!-- Your Content --> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This will give the `ScrollView` the knowledge it needs to scroll. Just make sure to set the `orientation` of your `LinearLayout`, such as `vertical`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textColor="#990099"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Words"
            android:textColor="#990099"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Words"
            android:textColor="#990099"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Words"
            android:textColor="#990099"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I always get an error when I add the scroll view outside the linear layout

Comment: Namespace Android is not found

Comment: I updated my answer, using your layout. This works fine for me.

Comment: No problems. Have fun!